# Maximum line length of markdown for HTML email?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I've got HTML email which has inlined styles and some heavy content (forcing outlooks to see transparent png), which results in lines longer than 1000 characters of markup. The text is far below the standard 80 chars.

This is not accepted by my html sender service - I received a warning about lines being too long, which can cause errors in some clients.

I have thoroughly tested those emails, and I haven't seen any problems with rendering of the HTML itself, but further reading and investigating the issue indicated that in fact some of the servers might reject the email message due to that length, and possibly line buffer overflows. Its that still valid? Should I be worried with html email markup length? We're at brink of 2015 after all.

The markup goes along the lines of that:

```
<img src="domain.com/gfx/logo_red.png" style="width: 257px; height: 79px; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%; float: none; clear: none; display: inline; line-height: 0px; position: relative; behavior: expression((this.runtimeStyle.behavior='none')&amp;&amp;(this.pngSet?this.pngSet=true:(this.nodeName == 'IMG' &amp;&amp; this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')&gt;-1?(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = 'none', this.runtimeStyle.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='' + this.src + '', sizingMethod='image')', this.src = './gfx/spacer.gif'):(this.origBg = this.origBg? this.origBg :this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url('domain.com/,).replace(')',''), this.runtimeStyle.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='' + this.origBg + '', sizingMethod='crop')', this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = 'none')),this.pngSet=true)); margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say you can ignore this particular warning.  Your sender service is being paranoid because it doesn't realise you are sending out a html email.  It is probably old and designed for sending text/plain emails.  Years ago, some very bad email clients would truncate urls which wrapped on to multiple lines.

But please do make sure you are sending using the correct mime type **text/html**, or using html within a multipart message.  There is no reason for a server to reject a html email for width reasons.